# having trouble editing members of an array of structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to create a function where I read in a file of time and x, y, z coordinate data. I'm using a for loop and if for any i and i+1 the times are the same I'm averaging their coordinate positions, overwriting i with these averages and then overwriting i+1 with NAN.

```
struct  Data {
  double Time_Data;
  double X_Data;
  double Y_Data;
  double Z_Data;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  const int SIZE = 3694;
  char Input[80] = "output.csv";
  const char Deliminator[2] = ",";
  char* field;
  char line[50];

  struct Data dataPoints[SIZE];
  FILE * pointer;
  fpointer = fopen(Input, "r");

  if(fpointer == NULL){
    printf("Unable to open file \n");
    return 0;
  }   
  int LineCount = 0;
  while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fpointer) != NULL){

    field = strtok(line, Deliminator);
    dataPoints[LineCount].Time_Data = atof(field);

    field = strtok(NULL, Deliminator);
    dataPoints[LineCount].X_Data = atof(field);

    field = strtok(NULL, Deliminator);
    dataPoints[LineCount].Y_Data = atof(field);

    field = strtok(NULL, Deliminator);
    dataPoints[LineCount].Z_Data = atof(field);

    LineCount++;
  }

  fclose(pointer);

  struct Data* structPointer[] = &dataPoints[];

  double average_X;
  double average_Y;
  double average_Z;

  for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++){

    average_X = 0;
    average_Y = 0;
    average_Z = 0;

    if(dataPoints[i].Time_Data = dataPoints[i+1].Time_Data){

      average_X = (structPointer[i]->X_Data + structPointer[i+1]->X_Data)/2;
      average_Y = (structPointer[i]->Y_Data + structPointer[i+1]->Y_Data)/2;
      average_Z = (structPointer[i]->Z_Data + structPointer[i+1]->Z_Data)/2;

      structPointer[i]->X_Data = average_X;
      structPointer[i]->Y_Data = average_Y;
      structPointer[i]->Z_Data = average_Z;

      structPointer[i+1]->Time_Data = NAN;
      structPointer[i+1]->X_Data = NAN;
      structPointer[i+1]->Y_Data = NAN;
      structPointer[i+1]->Z_Data = NAN;
    }
  }
  for(int i=0; i < SIZE; i++){
    printf("%d    %lf    %lf    %lf    %lf\n", i, 
          structPointer[i]->Time_Data,
          structPointer[i]->X_Data,
          structPointer[i]->Y_Data,
          structPointer[i]->Z_Data);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to use structPointer to access and overwrite the data. I've done a bunch of reading on pointers but I'm not having any luck getting it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

> ```
> if(dataPoints[i].Time_Data = dataPoints[i+1].Time_Data){
> ```

you do not check the time is the same, you want :

```
 if(dataPoints[i].Time_Data == dataPoints[i+1].Time_Data){
```

In the first *for* :

> ```
> for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
> ```

you do not consider the number of elements you read, so you can access to non initialized elements of the array with an undefined behavior. You must limit the loop depending on *LineCount*, and because you use the indexes *i* and *i+1* the end test must be `i<LineCount-1`

In the second *for*

> ```
> for(int i=0; i < SIZE; i++){
> ```

must be

```
for(int i=0; i < LineCount; i++){
```

but note you will print entries set to NAN.

Why that line :

> ```
> struct Data* structPointer[] = &dataPoints[];
> ```

you wanted

```
 struct Data* structPointer = dataPoints;
```

and that new variable is useless, you can continue to use *dataPoints* because you access to the elements using an index rather than through a pointer you increment.

Out of that doing

> ```
> while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fpointer) != NULL){
> ```

without considering can read more elements than *SIZE* is dangerous because you can write out of the array with an undefined behavior, do for instance

```
while((LineCount != SIZE) && (fgets(line, sizeof line, fpointer) != NULL)){
```

You also never check `strtok` does not return *NULL*, in case the file is invalid you will call `atof(NULL)` with an undefined behavior, better check `strtok` result to break the loop when the file is invalid.

Also `atof` does not detect errors, if the file is invalid and does not contains valid floating point you will work on 0 without knowing that, better to use for instance `strtod` to detect the errors.

When you are in the case the time is the same after doing all the `structPointer[i+1]->xx = NAN;` better to increment *i* to skip that entry of the array.

Also

> ```
> char Input[80] = "output.csv";
> ...
> const char Deliminator[2] = ",";
> ```

can be replaced by

```
 const char * const input = "output.csv";
 ...
 const char * const Deliminator = ",";
```

---

For instance, simplifying your code and using a dynamic allocated array to not be limited except by the virtual memory size :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct  Data {
  double Time_Data;
  double X_Data;
  double Y_Data;
  double Z_Data;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  const char * const input = "output.csv";
  FILE * fpointer = fopen(input, "r");
  
  if (fpointer == NULL){
    perror("Unable to open file");
    return 0;
  } 
  
  struct Data * dataPoints = NULL; /* or malloc(0) if you prefer */
  int lineCount = 0;
  double t,x,y,z;
  
  while (fscanf(fpointer, "%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf", &t, &x, &y, &z) == 4) {
    /* may be bypass rest of line */
    
    dataPoints = realloc(dataPoints, sizeof(*dataPoints) * (lineCount + 1));
    if (dataPoints == NULL) {
      fputs("not enough memory", stderr);
      return 0;
    }
    dataPoints[lineCount].Time_Data = t;
    dataPoints[lineCount].X_Data = x;
    dataPoints[lineCount].Y_Data = y;
    dataPoints[lineCount].Z_Data = z;
    lineCount++;
  }
  
  fclose(fpointer);
  
  for (int i=0; i<lineCount-1; i++) {
    if (dataPoints[i].Time_Data == dataPoints[i+1].Time_Data){
      dataPoints[i].X_Data = (dataPoints[i].X_Data + dataPoints[i+1].X_Data)/2;
      dataPoints[i].Y_Data = (dataPoints[i].Y_Data + dataPoints[i+1].Y_Data)/2;
      dataPoints[i].Z_Data = (dataPoints[i].Z_Data + dataPoints[i+1].Z_Data)/2;
      
      i += 1;
      dataPoints[i].Time_Data = NAN;
      dataPoints[i].X_Data = NAN;
      dataPoints[i].Y_Data = NAN;
      dataPoints[i].Z_Data = NAN;
    }
  }
  
  for (int i=0; i < lineCount; i++) {
    printf("%d    %f    %f    %f    %f\n", i, 
           dataPoints[i].Time_Data,
           dataPoints[i].X_Data,
           dataPoints[i].Y_Data,
           dataPoints[i].Z_Data);
  }
  
  free(dataPoints);
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat output.csv 
1,2,3,4
11,22,33,44
11,10,30,40
11,11,31,41
2,20,30,40
3,2,3,4
3,23,33,43
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
0    1.000000    2.000000    3.000000    4.000000
1    11.000000    16.000000    31.500000    42.000000
2    nan    nan    nan    nan
3    11.000000    11.000000    31.000000    41.000000
4    2.000000    20.000000    30.000000    40.000000
5    3.000000    12.500000    18.000000    23.500000
6    nan    nan    nan    nan
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

But normally a *csv* file has a header line, in that case it must be bypassed before to read the values, so for instance do :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct  Data {
  double Time_Data;
  double X_Data;
  double Y_Data;
  double Z_Data;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  const char * const input = "output.csv";
  FILE * fpointer = fopen(input, "r");
  
  if (fpointer == NULL){
    perror("Unable to open file");
    return 0;
  } 
  
  /* bypass header line */
  int i;
  
  while (((i = fgetc(fpointer)) != '\n') && (i != EOF))
    ;
  
  struct Data * dataPoints = NULL; /* or malloc(0) if you prefer */
  int lineCount = 0;
  double t,x,y,z;
  
  while (fscanf(fpointer, "%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf", &t, &x, &y, &z) == 4) {
    /* may be bypass rest of line */
    
    dataPoints = realloc(dataPoints, sizeof(*dataPoints) * (lineCount + 1));
    if (dataPoints == NULL) {
      fputs("not enough memory", stderr);
      return 0;
    }
    dataPoints[lineCount].Time_Data = t;
    dataPoints[lineCount].X_Data = x;
    dataPoints[lineCount].Y_Data = y;
    dataPoints[lineCount].Z_Data = z;
    lineCount++;
  }
  
  fclose(fpointer);
  
  for (i=0; i<lineCount-1; i++) {
    if (dataPoints[i].Time_Data == dataPoints[i+1].Time_Data){
      dataPoints[i].X_Data = (dataPoints[i].X_Data + dataPoints[i+1].X_Data)/2;
      dataPoints[i].Y_Data = (dataPoints[i].Y_Data + dataPoints[i+1].Y_Data)/2;
      dataPoints[i].Z_Data = (dataPoints[i].Z_Data + dataPoints[i+1].Z_Data)/2;
      
      i += 1;
      dataPoints[i].Time_Data = NAN;
      dataPoints[i].X_Data = NAN;
      dataPoints[i].Y_Data = NAN;
      dataPoints[i].Z_Data = NAN;
    }
  }
  
  for (i=0; i < lineCount; i++) {
    printf("%d    %f    %f    %f    %f\n", i, 
           dataPoints[i].Time_Data,
           dataPoints[i].X_Data,
           dataPoints[i].Y_Data,
           dataPoints[i].Z_Data);
  }
  
  free(dataPoints);
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat output.csv 
time,x,y,z
1,2,3,4
11,22,33,44
11,10,30,40
11,11,31,41
2,20,30,40
3,2,3,4
3,23,33,43
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
0    1.000000    2.000000    3.000000    4.000000
1    11.000000    16.000000    31.500000    42.000000
2    nan    nan    nan    nan
3    11.000000    11.000000    31.000000    41.000000
4    2.000000    20.000000    30.000000    40.000000
5    3.000000    12.500000    18.000000    23.500000
6    nan    nan    nan    nan
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful! Makes much more sense than most of the stuff I've been reading!